# How to get MySQL database to appear on index.php

Tags: php, database, ajax, mysql

I have a submission form on my website (index.php) and I have the data(user submissions) being stored into a MySQL database. Right now, I have the user submitting a post and then the page directs them to an update.php which shows what they inputed.

However, I want all of the data in the database in MySQL to be shown on the index.php. It's a lot like a comment system. User submits a post... and sees their post above the other submitted posts all on the same page. I think I'm missing AJAX... ?

Here is the code for index.php

```
   <div align="center">
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <h2 align="center" class="Title"><em><strong>REDACTED</strong></em></h2>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="update.php">
<hr />
<label><br />
  <form action="update.php" method="post">
 REDACTED: <input type="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  </label>
</form>
</div>
```

On update.php I have this:

```
   ?php
   $text = $_POST['text'];
   $myString = "REDACTED";

   mysql_connect ("db----.net", "-----3", "------------") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db ("-----------");

   $query="INSERT INTO TextArea (ID, text) VALUES ('NULL', '".$text."')";

   mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');

   echo " $myString "," $text ";

    ?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to learn basics first, no offense.

Comment: I'm leaving now so maybe someone else can answer ur questions, anyways here r some tips:1)you can submit the form to the same page `index.php` (without ajax) using the same code in the `update.php` page AND also having a DIV above the form where you retrieve all Data from DB and output them in it 2)u r not "securely" preparing the data to be inserted in the DB!

Comment: Start by cleaning up the nested forms, that is generally a bad idea. Then break down the rest into easier chunks: Submitting and storing a value in the database. Querying all the values and displaying them. Then putting them together on a single page.

Comment: Appreciating all the comments -- @Webarto, I know haha. I am just learning while working towards this small project.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed your HTML a bit, mainly to get rid of the nested `form` tags:

```
<div align="center">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 align="center" class="Title"><em><strong>REDACTED</strong></em></h2>
    <form method="post" action="update.php">
        <label for="text">REDACTED:</label> <input type="text" name="text" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

It still isn't fantastic though, you should:

- Change `<div align="center">` to `<div id="container">`, and then in your CSS set `#container {text-align:center}`.
- Get rid of `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, instead `#container {padding-top:24px}`.
- Change `<h2 align="center" class="Title"><em><strong>REDACTED</strong></em></h2>` into `<h2>REDACTED</h2>` and add to the `.Title` CSS rule: `text-align: center; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic`.
- Your `input` should probably have a better name than `text`.

Adjusted PHP:

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['text'];
$myString = "REDACTED";

mysql_connect ("db----.net", "-----3", "------------") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("-----------");

$query = "INSERT INTO TextArea (ID, text) VALUES (NULL, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($text) . "')";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());

echo "$myString - $text<hr />";

$query = "SELECT text FROM TextArea ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Error querying database:' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['text'] . '<hr />';
}

?>
```

- AJAX makes it much more complicated, so I didn't use it.
- Now, when someone submits to `update.php`, the submitted text will appear, and underneath it all the previous submissions.
- I added `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection. This is very important to do or malicious users can do things such as delete all your data. See: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+injection), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [Obligatory xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)
- I added `mysql_error()` so if your SQL fails, you will have a better idea why.

Comment: Wow.. thirtydot I can't believe you went out of your way to help me this much. I have much to learn. Thank you so much. Ahhhh thank you thank you. I would upvote if I could but I have only been in this game for two weeks

Answer (score 0):

to show the data in the same page, you have to do as under:

```
<form method="post" action=**"index.php"**>
    <label for="text">REDACTED:</label> <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" onsubmit="addInputedData"/>
</form>
```

and to show the inputted data in the same page, you have to create a function that use AJAX  to add element to your pages as **p** ,tag **h3** tag, etc  in which you input the data you want to displa, etc,and called in the onsubmit event of the :
(look above)